# How to avoid URL encoding with bit.ly?

Tags: url-shortening, bit.ly

I am using `bit.ly` linked with my Twitter Account to write tweet directly from their web site. Today I had the need to write an announce that mentions a site name, `TF2Maps.net`.

The problem is that `bit.ly` wants to convert it using its encoding but in this case I would prefer leave the name.

How can I avoid URL encoding in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to click on `Share Settings` (Right under your tweet) then uncheck

> Auto-shorten my long links (uncheck to
>   manually shorten links).

Now you can post without having your link shortened.

Answer (score 2):

Why making things complicated? Since you are doing it from [bit.ly](http://bit.ly) I guess they don't want that to happen. So for these special tweets, just use the [Twitter](http://twitter.com) directly. It's only 140 characters anyway.